# HighCharts synchronisation tooltip effect other chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using multiple highChart in a dashboard page e.g linearea, spline, pie and synchronisation of multiple charts

Set tooltip synchronisation for prototype

```
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
    return undefined;
};

Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function (event) {
    this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
    this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip
    this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
};
```

But above function effect all highchart e.g linearea and spline chart etc. what I want to apply on synchronisation only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this **live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/eec3mg9t/

I put every chart to a separate container - it's easier to manipulate them then. `class="sync"` indicates that chart should be synchronized:

```
<div id="container0"></div>
<div id="container1" class="sync"></div>
<div id="container2" class="sync"></div>
```

Then I set common events using this class:

```
$('.sync').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
   (...)
```

I applied **wrapping** instead of overwriting for `Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset` function so that the default action fires for unsynchronized charts.

```
  // Custom wrap
  Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Pointer.prototype, 'reset', function(proceed, allowMove, delay) {
    if (!this.chart.options.chart.isSynchronized) {
      proceed.apply(this, allowMove, delay);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Highcharts wrap working, When bind reset prototype fire mouse movement, But when mouseleave highchart div even change page but still watching mouse movement can you tell me how to stop watching mouse movement